# Status bar notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to implement a status bar notification and have some sound, and flashing alert to the user.

The sound plays very fine, but the problem is it stops just the user click on the status bar.

I want to continue playing the sound until the user does not want to stop it by clicking any button on it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put play your sound again and again thru `infinite loo`p and `maintain a bool` value to start and stop your sound as when user presses make it true and on another click make it false and exit the loop.You can use `sharedPreferences` to store the bool value.

Comment: Oh, i use the notification, so how it is possible, when notification starts the sound plays and i get the icon in the status bar, and then when just click on the status bar icon sound stops, so i want not to stop on just click the notification tab

Comment: didn't you show your own UI on the notification click? It it is so then you can't use above approach. I think you should go for some definite time to play the sound......

Comment: are you asking for how to play sound for definite time? For this you can take your media file of your time duration and if not then you can repeat the sound thru a loop for your desired duration....